# C# Comparaison between Dictionary<string, int> and value in enter

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, compare

I have a function for stock many string associate to int:

```
public int Scale(string value)
{
 this.stringToInt = new Dictionary<string, int>()
 {
  {"1p",00},{"2p",01},{"3p",03} ... {"300p",40}
 };
// Here i try to do something like that: if(value == (String in dictionary) return associate int
}
```

So i try to do a comparaison between string receive in enter and string in my dictionary for return associate int.

Any idea?

Thanks you for help !

Comment: What are you asking about? [`ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: What should be returned if there is no matching `int`? Why `Scale` has return type of `int`?

Comment: @GuruStron It was a mistake, i edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ContainsKey()` method of `Dictionary` to check if the key is present in dictionary:

```
if (this.stringToInt.ContainsKey(value)
{
    return this.stringToInt[value];
}
else 
{
    // return something else
}
```

Another way is to use `TryGetValue()`:

```
var valueGot = this.stringToInt.TryGetValue(value, out var associate);

if (valueGot)
{
    return associate;
}
else 
{
    // return something else
}
```